# In a PowerShell function, does BEGIN{} save any processing/memory?

Tags: powershell

In a PowerShell class I'm taking, we were being introduced to the `BEGIN{}` and `END{}` blocks of a PowerShell function, and how you could use them to do things like manage connections.

This got me thinking:

1. Imagine I was establishing some sort of object that had a large memory footprint, or took some noticeable time to generate. Do the `BEGIN{}` and `END{}` blocks reduce any memory/processing costs, especially if my function was being used in a pipe?
2. Why would you want to use this instead of `try`/`catch`/`finally`?  If you establish a connection and some part of the code fails, wouldn't you want a `finally` block to close the connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Re 1:

`begin` and `end` blocks inside a script or function execute *once* per call, namely before and after pipeline input is processed, which happens in the `process` block, which is invoked *once for each pipeline input object* - see [about_Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions#long-description).

Therefore, it makes sense to:

- place *one-time initializations* that need not vary depending on a given pipeline input object - such as as database connection - in the `begin` block
- and perform any necessary cleanup in the `end` block.

The *caveat* is that your `end` block may situationally *not* get to execute, namely if:

- a downstream cmdlet (one in a later pipeline segment) cause a *terminating* error
- the [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) cmdlet stops the pipeline prematurely via its `-First` parameter.

There is a *pending improvement* (as of this writing):

- A post-v7.2 version will allow use of a `clean` block (the name may change) that can be used for cleanup that is *guaranteed* to execute - see [RFC #294](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-RFC/pull/294/files).

---

Re 2:

- A [`try` / `catch`/ `finally` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) can only be placed *inside* one of the three available blocks (`begin`, `process`, `end`), and only inside that block is `finally` then guaranteed to execute.
- Using *none* of the the three blocks means that the function's body  is *implicitly* placed in the `end` block, i.e. is only ever executed *once* per call. (Such functions are usually *not* designed for pipeline input.)

The above implies that you cannot use a single `try` / `catch`/ `finally` statement for once-per-call initialization and cleanup if you also want to support per-object processing via `process`, because the initialization and cleanup then have to be in *different blocks* (`begin` vs. `end`).

Once the future `clean` block mentioned above is available, cleanup should be moved into the `clean` block for guaranteed execution.

---

**Example**:

This sample code shows the use of the `begin` / `process` / `end` blocks in an advanced [script *block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) invoked with `&`, for brevity (what is inside `& { ... }` can be used as-is as a function or script body).

It creates and opens an output file in the `begin` block, writes each pipeline input object to it in the `process` block, then closes the file in the `end` block (this example is contrived; in real life, you'd simply use [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content)).

```
1, 2, 3 | & {
  param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)] $InputObject)
  begin   { 
    Write-Verbose "Initializing: Opening output file (stream writer)" 
    try {
      $streamWriter = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "$PWD/sample.txt"
    } catch { throw } # Abort, if an exception occurred.
  }
  process { 
    Write-Verbose "Saving to file: $InputObject" 
    $streamWriter.WriteLine($InputObject) 
  }
  end     { 
    Write-Verbose "Cleaning up: Closing file" 
    $streamWriter.Dispose() 
  }
} -Verbose
```

The results are saved in file `sample.txt` file in the current directory (be sure to remove it manually), and the following verbose output prints to the display, illustrating how the blocks are invoked in response to the pipeline input (`1, 2, 3`):

```
VERBOSE: Initializing: Opening output file (stream writer)
VERBOSE: Saving to file: 1
VERBOSE: Saving to file: 2
VERBOSE: Saving to file: 3
VERBOSE: Cleaning up: Closing file
```

[This blog post](https://www.sapien.com/blog/2019/05/13/advanced-powershell-functions-begin-to-process-to-end/) contains a more detailed discussion.<sup>Thanks, [Hazrelle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5020462/hazrelle)</sup>